# Why does my normal map have grey squares on it

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I've baked a normal map for my project, and there are grey squares that show up on my normal map. Why is this happening?
[image: Normal Map]

This is the high poly model that the normal map is coming from.
[image: Model]

The grip tape on the model are a bunch of cylinders that are shrink wrapped to the bat.

Answer (score -1):

I figured the problem out. For some reason, removing the translucency map from the grip tape texture solved the problem.

Comment: "for some reason" is no reason at all.

Comment: @susu Could I ask why? I'm not too familiar with transmission as I don't use it that much, but from what I know, you plug in a translucency map, and it makes it transparent to a degree. My translucency map looks nothing like the grey squares on the map, and the tape isn't 100% transparent.

Comment: To get to the bottom of this, instead of a half-way answer, it would help if you added more information as part of the original question, no one else but you knows how you baked the map or what the original material looked like.

Comment: It is a weird problem and a weird solution.  There could be a bug in Blender.  Translucency really shouldn't affect a normal map bake.  I can understand if you're just happy the problem went away and don't want to investigate it any further, but further investigation is probably warranted by somebody.